# I keep getting a 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous' error when using multiple conditions with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror, ambiguous

I keep getting a 'ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().' error in my Python script.

Here's my code for reference (without the different imports and non-relevant code snippets):

```
for i in range(1, len(data)):
    position_size = portfolio_value.iloc[i-1] * position_size_pct

    # Check if the 50EMA crossed over the 200SMA
    if (in_position == 0) & (ema_50.iloc[i] > sma_200.iloc[i]) & (ema_50.iloc[i-1] <= sma_200.iloc[i-1]):
        in_position = 1
        pos_type = 'LONG'
        entry_price = data.iloc[i].mean()
        stop_loss = entry_price * (1 - stop_loss_pct)
        take_profit = entry_price * (1 + take_profit_pct)
        num_shares = position_size / entry_price
    elif (in_position == 0) & (ema_50.iloc[i] < sma_200.iloc[i]) & (ema_50.iloc[i-1] >= sma_200.iloc[i-1]):
        in_position = 1
        pos_type = 'SHORT'
        entry_price = data.iloc[i].mean()
        stop_loss = entry_price * (1 + stop_loss_pct)
        take_profit = entry_price * (1 - take_profit_pct)
        num_shares = position_size / entry_price
    else:
        continue
    
    # Check if the position should be closed
    if (in_position == 1) & (pos_type == 'LONG') & ((data.iloc[i].min() <= stop_loss) | (data.iloc[i].max() >= take_profit)):
        in_position = 0
        exit_price = data.iloc[i].mean()
        portfolio_value.iloc[i] = portfolio_value.iloc[i-1] + num_shares * (exit_price - entry_price)
    elif (in_position == 1) & (pos_type == 'SHORT') & ((data.iloc[i].min() >= stop_loss) | (data.iloc[i].max() <= take_profit)):
        in_position = 0
        exit_price = data.iloc[i].mean()
        portfolio_value.iloc[i] = portfolio_value.iloc[i-1] + num_shares * (entry_price - exit_price)
    else:
        continue
```

Here's the full error message that I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-416e46370df4> in <module>
      4 
      5     # Check if the 50EMA crossed over the 200SMA
----> 6     if (in_position == 0) & (ema_50.iloc[i] > sma_200.iloc[i]) & (ema_50.iloc[i-1] <= sma_200.iloc[i-1]):
      7         in_position = 1
      8         pos_type = 'LONG'

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1327 
   1328     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1329         raise ValueError(
   1330             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1331             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

As I am working with multiple conditions in Pandas, I know that I am supposed to use `&` instead of `AND` and `|` instead of `OR` but I keep getting the same error and can't find a way to fix it. I checked multiple Stack Overflow posts on the same error, but couldn't find something that works for me.
Thanks for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43484395/efficient-way-to-avoid-for-loops-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: It seems like one or more of your comparison values `ema_50.iloc[i]`, `sma_200.iloc[i]`  `ema_50.iloc[i-1]` `sma_200.iloc[i-1]` is a Series not a value that can be used for comparison. Check using such as `print(type(ema_50.iloc[i])` and so on. As @Celius Stingher is suggesting looping through DataFrames is usually best avoided and instead a vectorized approach used.